# Run foreach loop just one iteration with PHP

Tags: php

I have the following PHP to loop through images in my WordPres

```
function marty_get_images($post_id) {
global $post;

$thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id();

$images = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );

if ($images) :

    foreach ($images as $attachment_id => $image) :

    if ( $image->ID != $thumbnail_ID ) :

        $img_title = $image->post_title;   // title.
        $img_caption = $image->post_excerpt; // caption.
        $img_description = $image->post_content; // description.

        $img_alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); //alt
        if ($img_alt == '') : $img_alt = $img_title; endif;

        $big_array = image_downsize( $image->ID, 'large' );
        $big_img_url = $big_array[0];

        $thumb_array = image_downsize( $image->ID, 'thumbnail' );
        $thumb_img_url = $thumb_array[0];

        ?>

        <a href="<?php echo $big_img_url; ?>" class="thumb"><img src="<?php echo $thumb_img_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $img_alt; ?>" title="<?php echo $img_title; ?>" /></a>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif;
```

}

I'd like to just loop once. What do I change in my script?

Comment: above your endforeach add `exit;` or `die;`

Comment: http://secure.php.net/array_values http://secure.php.net/array_shift http://secure.php.net/array_keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) statement:

```
<?php endif; ?>
<?php break; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Fantastic, George! Will tick green in 5 minutes ;-)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk No problem Michael.

Answer (score 1):

Add `break;` after your HTML link. This will break out of the `foreach` loop and continue executing any other code which may be after the loop.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

```
<?php break; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> For only one iteration you can use "LIMIT" on query which will return only one record from database

```
$images = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID', 'limit' => '1') );
```

And for only one iteration for condition match

```
if ( $image->ID != $thumbnail_ID ) :
```

you can add break; before

```
 Break;
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

> which will check for one condition match for thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

Better to use array_slice and run the loop once

```
   foreach (array_slice($images,0,1 )as $attachment_id => $image) {
}
```

here, 
0 = index form where loop start,
1 = run the loop once